# Varrer objeto json com $.each jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Estou fazendo uma requisição a minha Servlet e pegando os dados json conforme o código abaixo:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $.post("MesaController",function(response){
          $.each(response,function(i,v){
             $("<button>")
               .text(v.nome).appendTo($("#mesas"));
           });
    //console.log(response);
       });
    });
```

Porém esta ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

```
    jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search 
    for 'length' in [{"id":1,"nome":"mesa 1"},{"id":2,"nome":"mesa 2"},
    {"id":3,"nome":"mesa 3"}]
    at w (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.success (mesa.js:8)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Comment: ja tentou fazer JSON.stringfy da response?

Comment: O que dá se colocares `console.log(typeof response, JSON.stringify(response));` antes da linha `$.each(response...`?

Comment: Quando eu coloco o comando que você informou Adelino aparece string "
       
        [{\"id\":1,\"nome\":\"mesa 1\"},{\"id\":2,\"nome\":\"mesa 2\"},
         {\"id\":3,\"nome\":\"mesa 3\"}]"

Answer (score 1):

A solução do meu problema foi colocar o seguinte comando na servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
      response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        ArrayList<Mesa> lista = new MesaDAO().listar();
        String listaJson = new Gson().toJson(lista);

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(listaJson);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MesaController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
    null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MesaController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
    null, ex);
    }
}
```

referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax